# Hyperref prepends citation key before bibliography entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref

I'm currently writing a research paper with the [AAAI style files](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Author/author.php). Here is what a minimal document that replicates the problem looks like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aaai18}
\begin{document}

\cite{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1810-04805}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
  \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Devlin \bgroup et al\mbox.\egroup
    }{2018}]{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1810-04805}
  Devlin, J.; Chang, M.; Lee, K.; and Toutanova, K.
  \newblock 2018.
  \newblock {BERT:} pre-training of deep bidirectional transformers for language
    understanding.
  \newblock {\em CoRR} abs/1810.04805.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: Citation without hyperref]

But here's what it looks like if I add a `\usepackage{hyperref}`:
[image: Citation with hyperref]

The link from the citation to the bibliography entry works fine. But I don't like that the citation key (in this example `[Devlin et al. 2018]`) is prepended in front of the reference. How can I turn this "feature" off? I'm open to modifying the style file if that's necessary.

Comment: In which order do you load hyperref and aaai?

Comment: Are you sure it should not be `\nocite{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1810-04805}`?

Comment: @samcarter See my comment on the answer below. If you load `hyperref` before `aaai18` it will not prepend the citation key, but the link won't work. If you load it after, the link works but you get the bad behavior from the screenshot in the question.
@AndiW Why would it be `\nocite`? This is just a minimal example, normally I would use this in a sentence, e.g. `Recently, BERT \cite{...} has achieved great results.`.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you load `hyperref` before the AAAI package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{aaai18}
\begin{document}

\cite{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1810-04805}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
  \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Devlin \bgroup et al\mbox.\egroup
    }{2018}]{DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1810-04805}
  Devlin, J.; Chang, M.; Lee, K.; and Toutanova, K.
  \newblock 2018.
  \newblock {BERT:} pre-training of deep bidirectional transformers for language
    understanding.
  \newblock {\em CoRR} abs/1810.04805.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While this does give the expected output, for some reason the links no longer work. So if you click on the citation it will now take you to the top of the document instead of the bibliography entry whereas previously it did.